# Python: Finding words using text file that matches string input without whitespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I am trying to create a function where it finds words from a string without whitespaces using a text file (e.g. dictionary.txt). It is similar to detecting words from a password.

My function currently takes in a single string and it will find it from the .txt file and print it out. My problem currently doesn't find any other words from that string. Regex might be the solution here, but I have no idea how to implement that from my code. I tried using a forloop using regex, but it would not work. I commented it out because the line seems to not work.

Here is my code:

```
#import re
def filesearch(userstring):
try:
    filename = "words.txt"
with open(filename) as search:
    for line in search:
        line = line.rstrip()
#         for word in re.findall(r'\w+', line):
        if userstring.lower() == line.lower():
            print("\nWords found in file: \n")
            print(line)

except OSError:
print("ERROR: Cannot open file.")

filesearch("cars")
filesearch("holidays")
filesearch("runningaway")
filesearch("abcgobears124")
```

Note: The last two of the outputs will not run.

The output for filesearch("runningaway") should print the words 'running' and 'away'.

For filesearch("abcgobears124"), the output should print the words 'go' and 'bears'.

How can I make those last two outputs run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` with an alternation pattern that includes all the words in `words.txt`:

```
import re
def filesearch(userstring):
    print('\n'.join(re.findall('|'.join(map(str.rstrip, open("words.txt"))), userstring, re.IGNORECASE)))
```

Comment: It worked, but how can I display just the specific words in that string? I want to be able to implement that with the code I have. Is there a line where I can use re.findall on my code?

Comment: Which specific words are you referring to? Your existing code is not structured in a way that can easily use `re.findall`. Might as well rewrite it like the example in my answer.

Comment: like for filesearch("abcgobears124") it is suppose to print out the words 'go' and 'bears' in a new line because it detected those words.

Comment: no, it just repeats the strings detected that are found in that file. For filesearch("abcgobears124") it just gives me "abcgobears124" as the output. Not 'go' and 'bears'

Comment: It won't do that. I don't think you're executing my example code correctly. Please run demo: https://repl.it/repls/MarvelousPossibleRobodoc

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I will do that for ya!